# Right order #define macro in C/C++

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I try save variable name like this:

```
#define TEST someVariable
#define makeString(x) #x

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char TEST[] = makeString(TEST);
    printf("%s    %s\n", TEST, makeString(TEST));
    return 0;
}
```

Output is :

```
appden4ik@appDen4ik:/opt/preprocessor/Debug$ ./preprocessor 
TEST    TEST'
```

I want next output:

```
someVariable      someVariable
```

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define TEST variable
#define makeStr(x) #x
#define makeString(x) makeStr(x)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char TEST[] = makeString(TEST);
    printf("%s    %s\n", TEST, makeString(TEST));
    return 0;
}
```

this helps

Comment: Nice! Maybe try to include an explanation of why your solution works, while the first one doesn't